# Gitlab-ci.yml Docker executer cannot run shell commands

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a ubuntu 18.04 server installed Gitlab-EE in it. I can access my runners and many other thing. I want to setup CI/CD with GitLab.
So lets begin :

Error :

[image]

My gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:latest

services:
- docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy


build:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  tags:
  - api
  before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -y
  script:
    - npm install


deploy:
  services:
    - node:latest
  image: node:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - api
  script:
    - sudo apt install python-pip
    - sudo pip install docker-compose
    - npm run dc:up ( this makes docker-composer build )
```

build stage completes successfully
deploy stage give error.

My Gitlab Runner :

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Api-Runner"
  url = "XX"
  token = "XXX"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

I want to install docker-composer for my project to run. 
If I remove the 'sudo' command the output gives like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the image you are using (`node:latest`) does not include the command `sudo`. It also looks like it defaults to the `root` user, so maybe you can just avoid using `sudo` altogether?

You can explore the environment/container in which your job will be running by starting your own container from that image: `docker run --rm -ti node:latest bash`

If you can work it out manually by using a container like that, then you can use that recipe in your `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

In particular, though, keep in mind that gitlab will start a new container for each job, so you probably want to add `apt-get update -qq` to your `deploy` job as well.

Comment: I tried with the alpine:latest for the image but it didnt work as well. The main problem here is it cannot find the python-pip package if I remove sudo

Comment: so how can I change the root user to gitlab-runner user and what should I need to use other than node:latest for image ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you need to change the user. What I'm saying is that if you're `root`, then you don't need `sudo` anyway. As to why it "cannot find the python-pip package if I remove sudo", I suspect you really are just missing the `apt-get update` in the same job before you try to install. I'm also not suggesting that you use a different image, but that would depend on everything that you need to do in that job. Since `node:latest` is based on `Debian`, you can probably do whatever you need to do with that image.

Comment: You are right. It fixed my problem. Thank you very much